# What could cause `MyType *pType` to go from valid parameter before return to null upon return?

Tags: c++, parameters, null, arguments

Consider this method:

```
result MyClass::getBMPText(Osp::Graphics::Bitmap *pBMP, Osp::Base::String &outtext, const int index) const {
    //Do stuff
    AppLog("3 Returning %S, 0x%X", outtext.GetPointer(), (int)pBMP);
    return E_SUCCESS;
}
```

I call it like this:

```
String itemstr;
Bitmap *pBMP = null;
for (int i = 0; i < ItemCount(); ++i) {
    getBMPText(pBMP, itemstr, i);
    AppLog("got %d : %S 0x%X", i, itemstr.GetPointer(), (int)pBMP);
}
```

Now take a look at the log:

> 5537.642,INFO,P35,T00,A190,FileMan::getBMPText (401) > 3 Returning Images, 0xB96E2140
>   5537.643,INFO,P35,T00,A190,FileMan::Update1p2List (130) > got 0 : Images 0x0

To repeat my question/observation: The function logs its return value as meaningful and relevent having just set it. The client however gets back the same null reference it sent in.

Answer (score 3):

You're passing the pointer by value, so the original pointer never gets changed. Change the function signature to `Osp::Graphics::Bitmap * & pBMP` to pass the pointer by reference.

Comment: The number of times I thought I could get away with this over simplification. I bet I've done this elsewhere. wha-aye! Thanks, it works!

Answer (score 1):

If you'd like to change the original pointer, you'll have to pass it as a pointer or as a reference. For example. the function `getBMPTest` would be declared as

```
result MyClass::getBMPText(Osp::Graphics::Bitmap *& pBMP, Osp::Base::String &outtext, const int index) const
```

and called like

```
getBMPText(pBMP, itemstr, i);
```

If you prefer pointers, you can do it like this instead:

```
result MyClass::getBMPText(Osp::Graphics::Bitmap ** pBMP, Osp::Base::String &outtext, const int index) const

getBMPTest(&pBMP, itemStr, i);
```

Answer (score 0):

This is because you're not setting `*pBMP` inside the function (you set `pBMP`, the pointer type). Changing the pointer itself won't affect its target.

Likewise, with `index`, you're passing by value, so nothing comes out.